# I can't understand why does it not send Discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I can't understand why doesn't send the welcome message

Here's Code from index.js

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
  let chx = db.get(`welchannel_${member.guild.id}`);
  if (chx === null) {
    return;
  }

  client.channels.cache.get(chx).send(`Welcome to ${message.guild.name}`);
});
```

Here's Code From channel.js
module.exports = {

```
name: "channel",
  description: "Help Command",
  category: "Help",
  execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
    const db = require("quick.db")

    let channel = message.mentions.channels.first() //mentioned channel
    
    if(!channel) { //if channel is not mentioned
      return message.channel.send("Please Mention the channel first")
    }

    db.set(`welchannel_${message.guild.id}`, channel.id)
    
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#b5b5b5')
        .setTitle(`Channel set: ${channel.name} `)

    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
  }
}
```

EDIT: I found out the problem i didn't have a intent flag GUILD_MEMBERS
and also thanks UltraX that helped also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the reason is simple, you need to go to your [dev portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) then after choosing your bot/application just go to bot and you need to enable member intents `Server Member Intent` after that it should work, if it didn't just give it a 10 minute, then try again!

Comment: Nothing in the OP's question relates to accessing GuildMembers

Comment: It Might work for others but it didn't work for me :(

Comment: To send a welcome message aka greeting message you need to have the Server Member Intent enabled, because you're checking for the guildMemberAdd event apparently.

Comment: @Lokry you are already in my discord server, lets talk about it there, also wait a bit if it didn't work then dm, sometimes it takes time

Comment: True, I was assuming the event was already firing and the issue related to the channel not being found

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ensure you get a channel object within the event is to use the guild property off the emitted member.

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
      const { guild } = member;
      let chx = db.get(`welchannel_${member.guild.id}`);
      if(chx === null) {return}
        
      const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(chx);
      if (!channel) return;
      
      channel.send(`Welcome to ${message.guild.name}`)
         .catch(console.error);
})
```

You will need the Guild Member's intent enabled as stated in [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69288737/12464931) for the event to emit.